# Is there a way to remove items from Google's Personal Blocklist in Safari under OS X?

Tags: google-search

I've used Google's Personal Blocklist in the past in order to not see search results from sites with no value to me. I've got a problem now though where I have a lot of items being blocked, and they're fully relevant sites that I actively use.

My impression previously is that there was a Chrome plugin to manage your blocklist, but nothing like that for Safari under OS X.

I just now installed the blocklist extension on Chrome and there was only one item listed. Does anyone know how to reset or edit this list for Safari?

Here's a screenshot of what I currently see for a search once I scroll down to the bottom and click "Your personal blocklist blocked some results. Click this text to view or edit your blocked results."

[image: blocked search results (screenshot)]

Comment: What happens if you click the little blue down pointing triangle?

Comment: It just lets you choose from cached or similar results in case the site isn't loading. Not too useful.